# Observer pattern in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, design-patterns, plsql, pipe

Can I set hook on changing or adding some rows in table and get notified someway when such event araised? I discover web and only stuck with pipes. But there is no way to get pipe message immediately when it was send. Only periodical tries to receive.

Comment: Such hooks are usually referred to as `triggers`

Comment: Who (users, an application, ...) are you trying to notify?

Comment: @ChrisSaxon An application, which connected to DB

Comment: If one of A's was good for you, could you accept it? Q is still open.

Answer (score 7):

Implementing an Observer pattern from a database should generally be avoided.

Why?  It relies on vendor proprietary (non-standard) technology, promotes database vendor lock-in and support risk, and causes a bit of bloat. From an enterprise perspective, if not done in a controlled way, it can look like "skunkworks" - implementing in an unusual way behaviour commonly covered by application and integration patterns and tools. If implemented at a fine-grained level, it can result in tight-coupling to tiny data changes with a huge amount of unpredicted communication and processing, affecting performance.  An extra cog in the machine can be an extra breaking point - it might be sensitive to O/S, network, and security configuration or there may be security vulnerabilities in vendor technology.

If you're observing transactional data managed by your app:

- implement the Observer pattern in your app.  E.g. In Java, CDI and javabeans specs support this directly, and OO custom design as per Gang Of Four book is a perfect solution.
- optionally send messages to other apps.  Filters/interceptors, MDB messages, CDI events and web services are also useful for notification.

If users are directly modifying master data within the database, then either:

- provide a singular admin page within your app to control master data refresh OR
- provide a separate master data management app and send messages to dependent apps OR
- (best approach) manage master data edits in terms of quality (reviews, testing, etc) and timing (treat same as code change), promote through environments, deploy and refresh data / restart app to a managed shedule

If you're observing transactional data managed by another app (shared database integration) OR you use data-level integration such as ETL to provide your application with data:

- try to have data entities written by just one app (read-only by others)
- poll staging/ETL control table to understand what/when changes occured OR
- use JDBC/ODBC-level proprietary extension for notification or polling, as well mentioned in Alex Poole's answer OR
- refactor overlapping data operations from 2 apps into a shared SOA service can either avoid the observation requirement or lift it from a data operation to a higher level SOA/app message
- use an ESB or a database adapter to  invoke your application for notification or a WS endpoint for bulk data transfer  (e.g. Apache Camel, Apache ServiceMix, Mule ESB, Openadaptor)
- avoid use of database extension infrastructure such as pipes or advanced queuing

If you use messaging (send or recieve), do so from your application(s).  Messaging from the DB is a bit of an antipattern.   As a last resort, it is  possible to use triggers which invoke web services (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/dbcalloutws-howto-084195.html), but great care is required to do this in a very coarse fashion, invoking a business (sub)-process when a set of data changes, rather than crunching fine-grained CRUD type operations. Best to trigger a job and have the job call the web service outside the transaction.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the other answers, you can look at [database change notification](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-mar/o26odpnet-093584.html). If your application is Java-based there is specific documentation covering [JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/dbchgnf.htm), and similar for .NET [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/changenote.htm) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/featChange.htm); and there's another article [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/win06odp-099708.html).

You can also look at [continuous query notification](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25518/adfns_cqn.htm), which can be used from OCI.

I know link-only answers aren't good but I don't have the experience to write anything up (I have to confess I haven't used either, but I've been meaning to look into DCN for a while now...) and this is too long for a comment *8-)

Answer (score 3):

Within the database itself triggers are what you need. You can run arbitrary PL/SQL when data is inserted, deleted, updated, or any combination thereof.

If you need to have the event propagate outside the database you would need a way to call out to your external application from your PL/SQL trigger. Some possible options are:

1. [DBMS_PIPES](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_pipe.htm) - Pipes in Oracle are similar to Unix pipes. One session can write and a separate session can read to transfer information. Also, they are not transactional so you get the message immediately. One drawback is that the API is poll based so I suggest option #2.
2. Java - PL/SQL can invoke arbitrary Java (assuming you load your class into your database). This opens the door to do just about any type of messaging you'd like including using JMS to push messages to a message queue. Depending on how you implement this you can even have it being transactionally tied the INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statement itself. The listening application would then just listen to the JMS queue and it wouldn't be tied to the DB publishing the event at all.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your requirements use [triggers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm) or [auditing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/cfgaudit.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Look at DBMS_ALERT, DBMS_PIPE or (preferably) **AQ (Advanced queuing)** it's Oracle's internal messaging system. Oracle's AQ has its own API, but also can treated like Java JMS provider.

There are also techniques like Stream or (XStream) but those are quite complex.