# Java Desktop application using dbms_alert

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I have an idea to create a little Java desktop application that displays notification when it finds a new record in an oracle db.

I don't want all the desktop clients to run the queries so what I was thinking I would do was create one main process which runs the queries and lets all the other processes know when to display a notification.

I am limited to Oracle 9i so I can't use change notification. AskTom says that dbms_alert is a good alternative for Oracle 9i.

So from what I'm thinking now is that I will write a sqlplus script to run via the crontab which will periodically run a query and then issue a dbms_alert.

For my desktop applications I'm a bit confused. dbms_alert has methods like waitany and waittone. Does that mean that my desktop applications need to keep live active sessions to the database open for them to received dbms_alerts?

Can't I just get my desktop applications to connect periodically to the db and pick up any alerts that they have not been picked up yet?

Thanks

Comment: Ajax uses http as it's protocol. There must be a server listening for the request, so unless you want to run a web server on each of your clients, Ajax is not the right approach. Furthermore, PL/SQL has no facility that I am aware of to make web requests or any other socket-based requests. You could code a server that polls Oracle for new rows, and pushes notifications our to the clients that are connected to it through sockets. Then you only have one process hitting Oracle with polls.

Comment: Not sure an http approach will be appropriate. I'm not sure if you don't want the application to talk to the DB at all, or if you just want to avoid polling; if the latter you could look at change notification or the other options discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16255360/266304).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys. I had a look at change notification today but as I'm running Oracle 9i this is not an option. AskTom has said that for version 9i dbms_alert can be used as an alternative to change notification. I might change my original question to ask an architectural related question around dbms_alert

Answer (score 1):

I would create a db job that executes the queries. Furthermore I would create a maintenance table where to leave a notification incl. timestamp if a new recored was found. Every (Java) client has its own timestamp from last query of the maintenance table and so would register if a new recored was found. But you have to make sure that every client makes a query to the maintenance table in a special period of time.